# JMockitからMockitにスイッチする場合の疑問

Tags: java, mockito, jmockit

私は今までJMockitを使用しておりました。
とくに、試験対象のメソッド内で呼ばれる別のクラスをmock化し、「２回目でExceptionを発生させる」などの使用方法でつかってました。

JMockitを使用した以下のソースコードは正常に動作します。

```
public class TestClass{

 @Test
 public void test01(@Mocked TargetSubClass mock){
    
    //Arrange
    new Expecteions(){{
      mock.someMethod((String[])any);
      result = new Object[]{ null , new NullPointerException } //２回目でException発生
    }}

　  //Act
    Target target = new Target();
    target.targetMethod(); //ここでNullPointerExceptionが発生（期待通り）

　　//Assert
    /* 本来はここでExceptionが発生することを確認・略  */

 }
}
```

しかし、環境の問題でJMockitの代わりにMockitoを使用せざる得ない状況になりました。
同じテストをするために、私が試したコードは以下です。

Mockitoを使用した以下のソースコードは正常に動作しません。

```
public class TestClass{

 @Test
 public void test01(){
    
    //Arrange
    TargetSubClass mock = mock(TargetSubClass.class);
    dothrow(new NullPointerException()).when(mock).someMethod(any()); //本来は２回目で出したいが１回目でも失敗

　  //Act
    Target target = new Target();
    target.targetMethod(); //ここでExceptionが発生しない

　　//Assert
    /* 本来はここでExceptionが発生することを確認・略  */

 }
}
```

どなたか、解決方法をご存じないでしょうか。
ご助言よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

質問文中のコードが実際に何をやりたいものなのか理解できていませんが、

- [10. Stubbing consecutive calls (iterator-style stubbing)](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.10.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#10)

が該当するものだと思います。

```java
when(mock.someMethod(any()))
    .thenReturn(null)
    .thenThrow(new NullPointerException());
```

戻り値が `void` のメソッドに対しては次のようになります。

- [Stubbing consecutive calls on a void method](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.10.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doNothing--)

```java
doNothing().doThrow(new NullPointerException())
    .when(mock).someMethod(any());
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。返信がおそくなってしまい申し訳ありません。somemethodはvoidを返すので、whenメソッドは使用できませんでした。